# Include Integration test code with application code

Tags: maven, integration-testing

Currently my integration-test code lives seperate from application code repo. We would need to include integration test code with in application code repo.
Is there any easy way to include the automation code with application code, aswell can package & run it separately without affecting existing Unit Tests ?

Also, current application code is in maven multi module framework. So, need suggestion whether i can add this automation code as new module to build & package it independent of application code ?

Appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 1):

Look at using the maven failsafe plugin [1] for integration tests. You would simply include your integration test classes in your project along with your unit tests, and configure failsafe to select and execute those tests during the verify phase.

[1] http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html